# How can I solve the problem with Models in ASP.NET.MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem. I have posts on the wall. And if the user has entered the site, then he can send his response to the post. How do I make it so that when using my `TakeAnswer` method, I can create a new row in the database? Now I only save the user's response, but not the ID of the post to which he replied.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var posts = db.Posts.ToList();

    if (posts == null) 
        return View();

    var temp = new IndexModel();
    temp.Posts = posts;
    temp.PostID = 0;
    temp.IndexAnswer = "";

    return View(temp);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> TakeAnswer(IndexModel model, string PostID)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Answers.Add(new Answer { UserId = GetUserId, UserAnswer = model.IndexAnswer, PostId = int.Parse(PostID) });
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return View();
}

public class IndexModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string IndexAnswer { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

@model CourseProject.ViewModels.IndexModel

<form asp-action="TakeAnswer" asp-controller="Home">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        @foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
        {

            <div class="card my-3">
                <h5 class="card-header font-weight-bold">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => post.PostName)
                </h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(model => post.PostContent)</p>
                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="IndexAnswer">Your answer to this problem</label><br />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="IndexAnswer" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-PostID="@post.Id">Reply</button>
                        </div>
                    }

                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <p>Task created: @Html.DisplayFor(model => post.Date)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</form>
```

Comment: "I can create a new row in the database?" what do you mean?

Comment: @Serge db.Answers.Add( new Answer...) But i need PostID from my wall to add new row

Comment: You have to show your Post class too